# Ionic 3 view child scroll event listener won't execute when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, scrolltop, viewchild

I used a `ViewChild` using **Slides** in put the in my `<ion-scroll>` element inside a `<ion-slides>`. Now when the page entered or loaded I want to know the `scrollTop` position of that scroll even the page is loaded.

Here is the sample of my code below in my **ts file**

```
@ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;
```

refer to this element `<ion-scroll #scrollWeb scrollY="true">`

and now load the page and get the `this.scrollWeb` which the page did not recognize it after the first load of the page.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.getPosts()
    // console.log('Slider:', this.slider);
    console.log(this.scrollWeb)
    if (this.scrollWeb) {
      this.scrollWeb.addScrollEventListener((ev) => {
        console.log(ev.target.scrollTop)
        if (ev.target.scrollTop < 2) {
          this.pulling = true
          console.log('Less than two')
        } else {
          this.pulling = false
        }
      })
    }
```

When the page will enter the `scrollWeb` is `undefined` or **unknown**. But when I open another page and then if I go back the scrollWeb is now already known. But the weird thing is it only executes the event when I go back to that page. But why?

Here is the full copy of **html file**

```
<ion-slides #mySlider (ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChanged($event)" *ngIf="!spinner">

    <!-- Discover -->
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-scroll #scrollWeb scrollY="true">
        <div class="pins" [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': selectedSegment=='second' ? '42px' : '0'}">

          <ion-card class="pin" *ngFor="let post of posts" no-padding [ngStyle]="{'display': post?.hidden ? 'none' : 'inline-block'}">
           <!-- Some content here -->
          </ion-card>
        </div>
      </ion-scroll>
    </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
```

I have no logs when I first open the page.

But when I go to another page and decided to go back the scrollWeb already shows it's log right here below:

```
Scroll {_scrollX: false, _scrollY: true, _zoom: false, _maxZoom: 1, maxScale: 3, …}
maxScale
:
3
maxZoom
:
(...)
scrollX
:
(...)
scrollY
:
(...)
zoom
:
(...)
zoomDuration
:
250
_maxZoom
:
1
_scrollContent
:
ElementRef
nativeElement
:
div.scroll-content
__proto__
:
Object
_scrollX
:
false
_scrollY
:
true
_zoom
:
false
```

The log above should be executed when I load the page right? Because I put it in inside the `IonViewWillEnter` method. Even the `IonViewDidLoad` is not working either.

It only works when I go to another page and come back and boom it's working.

I tried to put it on the constructor but still not working even if I navigate to other page and comeback if the code is in the constructor.

Can someone shed some light for me?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a temporary solution for having the same problem out there.

I just put a `setTimeout` method and perform the action inside after one second.

Code here:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.scrollWeb)
      if (this.scrollWeb) {
        this.scrollWeb.addScrollEventListener((ev) => {
          console.log(ev.target.scrollTop)
          if (ev.target.scrollTop < 2) {
            this.pulling = true
            console.log('Less than two')
          } else {
            this.pulling = false
          }
        })
      }
    }, 1000)
```

This is just a temporary solution but it is working well on other device like tablets. It also works well in both `Android` and `iOS` **platform** Tested and proved.

**PS:** I didn't know whats the problem with `IonViewDidLoad` but I think that's the proper method to be used to. Correct me if I'm wrong